# exec() command in PHP file reporting process not found

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to run this command within a PHP file on a localhost webpage that runs on apache and PHP:

```
echo exec("/usr/bin/killall mplayer 2>&1", $result);
```

But it does not work, this command `print_r($result);` gives this output:

```
mplayer: no process found
Array ( [0] => mplayer(5003): Operation not permitted [1] => mplayer(5004): Operation not permitted [2] => mplayer: no process found )
```

Things I have tried are adding this to the /etc/sudoers

```
www-data    ALL=(ALL:ALL)   ALL
%www-data   ALL=(ALL:ALL)   ALL
```

This is a device that runs on an internal network in my home, so not a security risk.

I'm pretty sure it is a file/permission/ownership issue, but not sure what to do to allow it to run.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to run it as su, surely your command should be `sudo /usr/bin/killall ...`?

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for replying, if I add sudo I get this `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specifiedArray ( [0] => [1] => We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System [2] => Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things: [3] => [4] => #1) Respect the privacy of others. [5] => #2) Think before you type. [6] => #3) With great power comes great responsibility. [7] => [8] => sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified )`

Comment: Seems that you're not set up correctly to `sudo` without a password.

Comment: I'd agree, but I thought adding what I added to the sudoers file was for that exact purpose?

Comment: What you added allows `sudo` in general, but doesn't disable the password. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password for how to enable sudo without a password. You're missing the `NOPASSWD` option.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, along with adding it at the end of the sudoers line, thank you. If you'd like to put that as an answer I'll mark it resolved.